# Логичкая ошибка в запросе SQL

Tags: php, sql

Мне нужно получить данные из выборки. Если я ввожу в "access_id" несуществующий ID которого нет в таблице `access_rights` возвращает ноль строк.
Хотя строка должна быть со значениями NULL из таблицы `access_rights`
Как получить данные из выборки, если access_id в БД не существует?

```sql
SELECT access_rights.value, access_rights.user_id, access_rights.access_id, users.nickname, users.name, users.group_id 
FROM `sessions` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON sessions.user_id=users.id 
LEFT JOIN `access_rights` ON access_rights.user_id = users.id 
                         and access_rights.access_id = access_rights.access_id 
WHERE `session` = "z9YiXI7SdgddMxDnujSnRjBXeagLJpFB" and `access_id` = 24
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Поиграйте с `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t2.*
FROM ( SELECT @access_id AS access_id,
              @session AS session ) AS t1
LEFT JOIN data_source_tableset AS t2 ON t1.access_id = t2.access_id
                                    AND t1.session = t2.session
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Не вижу в данном случае предмета для пояснений. А лить воду просто так, лишь бы было, считаю лишённым смысла. Впрочем, если у автора останутся вопросы - пусть спрашивает, отвечу.